# Typescript nodejs Error: Cannot find module './package.json'

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am using nodejs 10.1.0

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-196:~/code/makeIt/chrome-render$ node -v
v10.1.0
```

I am using typescript2.8.3

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-196:~/code/makeIt/chrome-render$ tsc -v
Version 2.8.3
```

I've set up a directory for nodejs development like so:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-196:~/code/makeIt/chrome-render$ find
.
./tsconfig.json
./node_modules
. lotsof files in node_modules
. lotsof files in node_modules
. lotsof files in node_modules
./yarn.lock
./src
./src/makeIt.ts
./src/server.ts
./dist
./dist/src
./dist/src/server.js
./dist/src/makeIt.js
./dist/src/server.js.map
./package.json
./dist/src/makeIt.js.map
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-196:~/code/makeIt/chrome-render$
```

I compile the code OK with tsc - no errors.

When I run my code I get an error.

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-196:~/code/makeIt/chrome-render$ node dist/src/server.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:573
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './package.json'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:571:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:497:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/code/makeIt/chrome-render/dist/src/server.js:39:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:678:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:589:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:3)
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-196:~/code/makeIt/chrome-render$
```

There is no problem when move package.json into dist/src/

node dist/src/server.js

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-196:~/code/makeIt/chrome-render$ find
.
./tsconfig.json
./node_modules
. lotsof files in node_modules
. lotsof files in node_modules
. lotsof files in node_modules
./yarn.lock
./src
./src/makeIt.ts
./src/server.ts
./dist
./dist/src
./dist/src/server.js
./dist/src/makeIt.js
./dist/src/server.js.map
./dist/src/package.json
./dist/src/makeIt.js.map
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-196:~/code/makeIt/chrome-render$
```

Moving package.json does not seem like the right solution - I think I need it to be in my project root.

Can anyone suggest what should I be doing to avoid this error?

Am I configuring my nodejs/typescript project wrong?

Comment: Probably not related to your issue, `dist` should not contain `src` but only its files. Put the content of `tsconfig.json` into the question.

Comment: pls post code in this file > /home/ubuntu/code/makeIt/chrome-render/dist/src/server.js:39:20

Answer (score 2):

Credit to @hashtabe_0

My server.js file contained

const package_json = require('./package.json');

Removing it fixed the problem.